# Android SQLite Update Method Won't Update

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I've been away from java for a while and as a warmup, decided to run a basic database/list-keeping app to help me keep track of things I need as I move. I'm largely finished with the app, it runs roughly but well enough for my purposes, but I'm  having a lot of issues with the SQLite database functions. The only one I've yet to sort out is the "update" function.

Here is my current code, within my SQLITE Helper class:

```
public int updateObject(HomeObject originalObject, HomeObject updatedObject) {
    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", updatedObject.getName());
    values.put("room", updatedObject.getRoom()); // get title 
    values.put("have", updatedObject.getHave()); // get author

    // 3. updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_HomeObjects, //table
            values, // column/value
            KEY_ID+" = "+String.valueOf(originalObject.getId()), // selections
            null ); //selection args

    // 4. close
    db.close();

    return i; 
}
```

However, when I use the modify button which is meant to call this method and update the object correspondingly, it appears to simply delete the object. It disappears off of all lists and in-app searches reveal it to be no longer in the database.

Here's what the relevant code I use to call it looks like:

```
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String itemName = intent.getStringExtra(LivingRoom.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Redacted... There is a large section of code here
// which deals with pulling the newlyEditedName, newlyEditedHave,
// and newlyEditedRoom variables from different places in the view.

HomeObject newlyEditedObject = new HomeObject(newlyEditedName, newlyEditedHave, newlyEditedRoom);
HomeObject originalObject = db.getObject(itemName);
int test = db.updateObject(originalObject, newlyEditedObject);
```

I'm very new to SQLite, so maybe I'm missing something basic... But what's going wrong here? The log reveals that the method is returning "1". As another side-note, I can confirm that the "getObject" method works perfectly, as it gets used multiple times before this, so I know it's returning correctly.

Thank you for any assistance! If I can get this worked out, I can actually start using this thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your error. 
You could change your code to

```
int i = db.update(TABLE_HomeObjects, //table
        values, // column/value
        KEY_ID+" = '"+String.valueOf(originalObject.getId()) + "'", // selections
        null ); //selection args
```

or you could use the recommended method

```
int i = db.update(TABLE_HomeObjects, //table
        values, // column/value
        KEY_ID+" =?", // selections
        new String[]{String.valueOf(originalObject.getId())} ); //selection args
```

Comment: I updated my code (attempting to use both methods), but it's still giving me the same issue. Currently, I have it set to the latter (which is the coding from the tutorial I was working with), but it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Could you write a test function which runs a query and check what your updated row contains? Instead of searching for the updated object in the database, could you check and print out what the updated row contains using that particular KEY_ID?
This may help track down.

Comment: Also I just noticed this but why are you closing your database at the end of your function? You should not close your database while your app is yet running. Close it when you want to terminate your app. This may be causing you errors